# The command "aapt" does not support in shell script

Tags: android, shell, ubuntu-16.04, aapt

I went through all the questions and answers in Stackoverflow relevant to this question but non of the suggestions support me.

I have written a shell script which uses `aapt` as a command. I use Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit version. I have installed the  required 32 bit libraries as below but it doesn't work for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

However, I feel that there will be a PATH problem which I can not figure out exactly.

The error is as below.

> line 6: aapt: command not found

Comment: What error you getting ?

Comment: The error is 'line 6: aapt: command not found'

Comment: How you `.bash_profile` ?

Comment: `.bash_profile` is not available. But the `.profile` is as  below.
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
 . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Follow this to find the `.bash_profile` https://askubuntu.com/a/29241/642889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have many versions of `aapt` on your development machine, and most likely none will be in your `PATH`. You can find `aapt` in `$ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/.../`, where `...` is some version number of the build tools (e.g., `25.0.3`) and where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever your Android SDK is installed.

Comment: Updating PATH in `.profile`  correctly helps me to overcome this. problem solved.

Comment: @Malinda: Just remember that several updates to the build tools come out each year. Update your `PATH` every so often when you are ready to move to a new version of the tools.